# Wordpress Broken Themes

Tags: wordpress

In the WordPress 'Install Themes' option I have installed a theme called **Facelook** but after successful installation when I tried to activate it, following message appeared.

> The following themes are installed but incomplete. Themes must have a
>   stylesheet and a template. Name: Facelook. Description: The parent
>   theme is missing. Please install the "bp-default" parent theme.

Where I can install **bp-default**? What does this error message mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the "Facelook" theme is a child theme of the "bp-default" theme.  You'll need to locate the bp-default theme and install it before you can use Facelook.

Answer (score 0):

Check all uppercase/lowercase characters in the theme folder name match EXACTLY to the theme  reference inside Style.css match.

Often when Wordpress complains that a theme is not installed (either when trying to use the theme, or when referencing the parent from a child-theme), it is because of an uppercase/lowercase mismatch.

For example:

inside style.css...
    Template:     supertemplate

is not the same as the folder name "Supertemplate"

Seems trivial, but something to check.